# Finding Android Version Specifically - Whats Wrong?

Tags: android, android-emulator, version

Okay, so when i open my app, it should check for specific versions of a phone in order for it to run correctly. I dont want separate apps because that will annoy the user. I tried this:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 2.2.3 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 2.1){
        //Stuff goes here
        }
```

Now, this comes up as a basic error in Eclipse. Now, i could try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
 //Stuff goes here
 }
```

But if a user has a rooted phone with a custom ROM, it may show differently so that may show differently and another thing is that this only gives the phones OS's name, not the specific version. I tried writing this in Eclipse:

```
if(Build.VERSION.RELEASE >= 2.2.3 && Build.VERSION.RELEASE >= 2.1){
        //Stuff goes here
    }
```

It gives back an error in Eclipse. Any other good approach?

Answer (score 3):

> Now, this comes up as a basic error in Eclipse

That is because `SDK_INT` is a `int`, not a `float`. You can tell this by reading [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT).

Also, `2.2.3` is not a valid number in any programming language, AFAIK.

> But if a user has a rooted phone with a custom ROM, it may show differently so that may show differently and another thing is that this only gives the phones OS's name, not the specific version.

No, `Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD` is an `int`. You can tell this by reading [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#GINGERBREAD).

> It gives back an error in Eclipse

That is because `RELEASE` is a string, not a `float`. You can tell this by reading [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#RELEASE).

> Any other good approach?

Your second approach is the right one to use.

Comment: check "Android Version History" on Wikipedia, there are types of Android Froyo versions like 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, and 2.2.3. How can i detect between each other?

Comment: @MoyleJack: Generally, you do not need to. Nothing changed in the Android SDK in those maintenance releases.

Comment: I was doing an app for testing phones security. It will look for the phones version and then attempt public exploits on it. If one of these gets root access, a message pops up. Generally, im asking because i know there was a way to get an exact version of android but i stopped android coding 2 years ago so I forgot most of it.

Comment: @MoyleJack: Well, `RELEASE` is as close as you're going to get, but you have to pay attention to your data types. `RELEASE` is a string, and therefore cannot be numerically compared with `float` values. Besides, floating point numbers only have one decimal point, so `2.2.1` is not a `float`, either. And there is no guarantee that custom ROMs will use recognizable values there, since `RELEASE` is for display purposes only, not for developers to use for comparisons the way you are.

Comment: if your using a Custom ROM, im pretty sure your rooted. I didnt want my app to bug up if a user used a Custom ROM but then again, like I said, if your using a custom ROM, your rooted... Also, if you said that RELEASE is only for display purposes, how can I use it for other purposes like im using?

Comment: @MoyleJack: "how can I use it for other purposes like im using?" -- it is a `String`. You are welcome to use that `String` for any lawful purpose. I just do not know if it will meet your needs, given the fact that device manufacturers can put whatever they want in there. *Most* probably just put in the standard numbering scheme, but that's not assured.

Comment: Im pretty sure this project is "lawful" if a user needs it to test against common exploits. I just got sick of the average android app and wanted to expand.